# Is there a way to create a Typescript record where the property value uses the inferred string literal type of the property key?

Tags: javascript, typescript, object, record, typescript-generics

I want to be able to create a Record-like type, where each record property value is an object who's `id` property is a string-literal of the record key value.

This is what I've played around with so far, but the type of `id` for each record property value is still just a generic string.

```ts
type RecordById<K extends string, T> = {
    [key in K]: T & {
        id: key extends infer Inner ? Inner : unknown;
    }
}

const testRecord: RecordById<string, {[key: string]: any}> = {
    dog: {
        id: 'dog' // type of `id` is 'string' instead of string-literal 'dog';
    },
    cat: {
        id: 'cat'
    },
    mouse: {
        id: 'mouse'
    }
}
```

To clarify, what I'm trying to achieve is typescript would enforce the type of `id` to be the string literal `dog` for the first record property based on its property key. Is this something that is possible with Typescript?

Comment: Is this the sort of thing you're looking for? https://www.typescriptlang.org/play?#code/C4TwDgpgBA0hIGcASBDAbhAyigthAaigDYCuEAPAPIB8UAvFAN4CwAUFB1ANoDW8UASwB2UPiAD2AMyiUAugC4mbTisEATRWIDcyzgF82B1mwDG4oQmBRgESwCUIZgE5r6S9pzXiA5opYfVdUUAci9vYKgAekjrcGgpKAADATVEwQQoYMsnYXDBCxsUVwTs3IBaIgEbJ2JMsOCdAKg9ABpdDhMUYD921RSQzuBg3tbenHESBAgeppV+zPHJiGGmoz0oFAyzAsbTc0t8tGIUgBVbYAdnVwZ-FTCZwI554IAjFCceKDePlZVRpsGD0ez0Gv30bSaiymQMCzyhyxGhg2W32wEa2wOR0qGlg8GQ6CwuAIxDI5FAkASNnsjnELloDCpFxpLnRqMOxxxcEQqAw2DwhFIFHJEASwixp3Ol1panp7OxZ2pVy0QA

Comment: @BenjaminGruenbaum Mmm close but not quite. 

For the use case in mind, I won't be able to use const assertions as the record will have properties being added to it. 

In the given example, I was really just looking for something that would let me write a new record property with the key "bird" for example, and then when I type the property value, typescript would be able to autocomplete the id property value to "bird" when I begin typing.

Comment: Interestingly my example above kind of works if I pre-define the union type of values (e.g. RecordById<'cat' | 'dog' | mouse', ...>), but again that's really not what I'm after.

Comment: Yeah I think the union needs to be known at the time the object is created.  You can use a function to infer the union, but that still doesn't allow you to add additional properties after creation. https://tsplay.dev/wXR5om